# Showing that planes paralell to coordinate planes intersect at a point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Having three planes, each paralell to one of the coordinate planes,

Paralell to ***xy*** with ***z = c***

Paralell to ***yz*** with ***x = a***

Paralell to ***xz*** with ***y = b***

What would be the way to show they'd intersect at point *(a, b , c)*?

Comment: Plug-in its coordinates into each equation. You'll conclude it satisfies all of them. Therefore it belongs to the intersection.

Comment: Same way you'd show that the coordinate planes $z=0$, $x=0$, $y=0$ intersect at the origin.